# Arguments are always null when creating a fragment

Tags: java, android

I want to pass information between fragments. For this I am creating a Bundle in my BoothDetailFragment which I want to open in the GridFragment. Doing this has worked in other Fragments before, however now the arguments are always null when calling them in the OnCreateView.

I have read other threads where it was recommended to check whether ids are defined in the xmls and that is the case in my project.

Here I create the bundle

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("booth", booth);
                getMainActivity().showFragment(FragmentType.GRID, bundle);

            }
```

This is the showFragment-method in the MainActivity

```
 public void showFragment(FragmentType fragmentType, Bundle fragArgs) {
        showFragment(fragmentType, getSupportFragmentManager(), fragArgs);
    }

 public static void showFragment(FragmentType fragmentType, FragmentManager fm, Bundle fragArgs) {
        String fragmentTag = fragmentType.name();
        Fragment fragTarget = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
        //
        if (fragTarget != null || fragmentType.mainScreen) {
            // pop the stack until our target is on top, or we are at root level.
            popBackstackUntil(fm, fragmentTag);
        } else if (fragmentType == FragmentType.DEBUG_LOG || fragmentType == FragmentType.DEVICE_ERRORS) {
            // try to find the other one
            String otherFragmentTag;
            if (fragmentType == FragmentType.DEBUG_LOG) {
                otherFragmentTag = FragmentType.DEVICE_ERRORS.name();
            } else {
                otherFragmentTag = FragmentType.DEBUG_LOG.name();
            }
            Fragment otherFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(otherFragmentTag);
            if (otherFragment != null) {
                // pop the backstack up to and including the other fragment
                boolean b = popBackstackUntil(fm, otherFragmentTag);
                if (Constants.DEBUG) {
                    Preconditions.checkState(b, "FIXME");
                }
                // one more pop to remove the found other-fragment
                fm.popBackStack();
            }
        }

        // start transaction to modify the ActionBar, Footer, and if necessary,
        // the main container as well...
        final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        if (fragTarget == null) {
            fragTarget = createNewFragmentInstance(fragmentType, fragArgs);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragTarget, fragmentTag);
        }

        if (!fragmentType.mainScreen) {
            ft.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
        }

        ft.commit();
    }
```

Here I try to open the Bundle in the GridFragment

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
```

The CreateNewFragmentInstance-method

```
if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            log.d("createFragment " + fragmentType);
        }
        AbstractArgoFragment frag = fragmentType.newInstance();
        if (fragArgs != null) {
            frag.setArguments(fragArgs);
        }
        return frag;
```

The bundle ends up being null every time

Comment: Paste the body of method `createNewFragmentInstance(fragmentType, fragArgs)`

Comment: ```if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            log.d("createFragment " + fragmentType);
        }
        AbstractArgoFragment frag = fragmentType.newInstance();
        if (fragArgs != null) {
            frag.setArguments(fragArgs);
        }
        return frag;
```